# How to pass argument to function in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How can I send `sport_id` form `getSport` to `getEvents` to show each sports events?

Can I put `getSport` function to other component, call and use it in this component?

events json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "912653",
    "time": "1536471082",
    "time_status": "1",
    "league": {
      "id": "900",
      "name": "Hong Kong 2nd Division",
      "cc": "hk"
    },
    "home": {
      "id": "13767",
      "name": "Yau Tsim Mong",
      "image_id": "193606",
      "cc": "hk"
    },
    "away": {
      "id": "63770",
      "name": "Tuen Mun SA",
      "image_id": "56045",
      "cc": "hk"
    },
    "timer": {
      "tm": 74,
      "ts": 25,
      "tt": "1",
      "ta": 0
    },
    "scores": {}
  }
]
```

sports json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Rugby Union",
    "is_active": null,
    "slug": "rugby-union"
  }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";

export default class Feutred extends Component {
  state = {
    sports: [],
    events: [],
    isLoading: true,
    errors: null
  };
  getSports() {
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/sports.json")
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(sport => ({
          id: sport.id,
          name: sport.name,
          slug: sport.slug
        }))
      )
      .then(sports => {
        this.setState({
          sports,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
  getEvents() {
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/events?sport_id=${sport_id}")
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(event => ({
          id: event.id,
          time: event.time,
          league: event.league,
          time_status: event.time_status,
          homeTeam: event.home,
          awayTeam: event.away
        }))
      )
      .then(events => {
        this.setState({
          events,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.getSports();
      (this.interval = setInterval(
        () => this.getEvents({ time: Date.now() }),
        12000
      ));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { sports, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {!isLoading ? (
          sports.map(sport => {
            const { id, name } = sport;
            return (
              <div key={sport.id}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p className="meta">
                    <span className="matchinfo">
                      <span className="block">time</span>
                      <span className="block">timestatus</span>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <h3>
                    <a href="">home-team vs aya tream</a>
                  </h3>
                  <p className="league">
                    <a className="watchlive" href="">
                      <span className="icon" />
                      <span>Watch live</span>
                    </a>
                    <span>{sport.name} - league cc - league name</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just destructure it - load sports in one component then render some `<EventsLoadingComponent />` passing sport id as prop ...

**HINT**: Use `if(isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>` in render before 'main return' - no need to use ternary operator in return JSX.

**UPDATE:**

```
render() {
  const { sports, isLoading } = this.state;
  if(isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {sports.map(sport => <EventsLoadingComponent sport={sport}/>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Move `getEvents` into `<EventsLoadingComponent/>` - you'll be fething for events related to `this.props.sport.id` and render them. This way each of them can be separately updated.

Remember to use `key` in the topmost html element.

**UPDATE #2:**

> can you please give your code comparison with my code ?

Your code - linear, procedural, 'flat template-driven', forcing async to be sync, all-in-one-component ... while html is a (flatten view of) tree structure.

**[React thinking](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)** (generally, not my code only) - more OO, building tree of objects closer related to data and view structure, giving them own responsibility (data handling, view). Easier to read, expand (destructure further details to components - even one-liners), suitable to decorating, easy to manage ... and reuse.

Often object in structure renders only passed children (or nothing) only providing functionality. Available level of complexity is greater, communication within this structure is far easier (and less dependent) than (it could be done) in html.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: can you please give your code comparison with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
getEvents({ id }) {
    axios
      .get(`/api/v1/events?sport_id=${id}`)
      ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSports()
      .then(() => {
        return Promise
          .all(this.state.sports.map(this.getEvents))
      });
    ...
  }
```

**Note:**

You need to refine the way you *save* the data because you need to know which *events* are for which *sport*.